# Booting from GRUB help terminal? Manually setting /boot/ location?

Tags: boot, grub

In my last question:
[Grub install on a partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/573613/grub-install-on-a-partition)

I ran grub-install on my entire hard drive and now I am booting to the GRUB terminal with a prompt: grub>.
I've done some research and it seems like you can manualy set the boot from location (at least with ubuntu):
https://askubuntu.com/questions/616811/gnu-grub-terminal-instead-of-ubuntu-login-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1

I'm having some trouble figuring it out though. If I run ls I get a list of form (hd0, gptX) where X= 1,..,8. I should be booting from either gpt5 or 7. Running ls on those two gives:

```
ls (hd0, gpt5)/
    lost+found/ grub/
ls (hd0, gpt5)/grub/
     i386-pc/ themes/ fonts/ grubenv grub.cfg
ls (hd0, gpt7)/
    lost+found/ home/ boot/ var/ dev/ etc/ ...
```

The boot file on gpt7 is empty. How do I manually set the boot location and fix this? I'm not even concerned with dual booting to arch/windows, right now I just want to be able to boot to arch directly.

Comment: The boot directory should contain your kernel and initrd. Did you install the [essential packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Install_essential_packages)?

Comment: ok, I was able to boot from the flash drive and skip the grub menu, I installed the essential packages. What now? Grub install on the hard drive again?

Comment: Yes, [configure the system](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Configure_the_system), [install grub](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Installation_2)
and [generate grub.cfg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Generate_the_main_configuration_file).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you had the problem resolved, but here's my fix to it.

I did take some help from [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/) how to geek article.

So, basically I too being a distro freak was testing the zorin os and to uninstall it I straightup formatted the partition on my laptop.

Now on restarting the pc booted into grub terminal. And let me tell you that I did find a way to boot into windows from there but not ubuntu.

Here's what you do.

Following the article, you need to have your linux distro installed on a thumbdrive.

Now the way as you would usually install a linux distro, open the boot options and boot into the thumbdrive.

From here ubuntu has option to 'try', click it.
Once, the ubuntu os is loaded, open the terminal.
From here follow the article and install the boot-repair tool and let the app do its job.

You might get some error regarding NVram, ignore it.

Now, power off your PC, unplug the thumbdrive, and start pc and again enter the boot options, from there you may see that the grub menu is back!

But, we are not done yet, you will need to configure boot options so that you dont need to press f12 everytime you want to boot into windows.

go to the boot settings by pressing f2 on startup, and move the ubuntu so that it is placed before windows in the boot menu.

You're Done !! Congrats on having grub back in your life ;-) .